# can we change the general functionality of volume buttons?

Tags: applications, development

can we change the general functionality of volume buttons while specific service is playing in the background in my app(like using the volume buttons to skip the songs, using those button to drag up or down in the reading app etc)?

Comment: Is this for an app that you are making, or is it something that you want for the phone to do when you press on the volume button?

Comment: Yes you can.  There is Volkey Scroll as an example which allows you to use the volume buttons to scroll your phone. This sounds like an app development question to me.  @ABochur  I think we should vote to close this as too broad.